# Placing the element at last of sorted list

Tags: javascript

I am sorting on the basis of doc_status the items using sort function.
Everything is fine just one case when doc_requirment =0 I want it to be last element of items irrespective of its doc_status.

```
var lockStatus = 2;
var items = [
  { doc_requirement :4, doc_status :0 },
  { doc_requirement: 3,doc_status:1 },
  { doc_requirement:0,doc_status :2},
  {doc_requirement: 3 ,doc_status :3},
  { doc_requirement: 1,doc_status : 0},
];

if(lockStatus == 2){
  var finalSortedDocuments = items.sort(function(firstDoc,secondDoc){
        var order = [2,0,1,3];
        if(firstDoc.doc_status == secondDoc.doc_status && firstDoc.doc_status ==0){
        var orderNew = [ 1,4];
        return  orderNew.indexOf(firstDoc.doc_requirement) - orderNew.indexOf(secondDoc.doc_requirement);
       }
       return order.indexOf(firstDoc.doc_status) - order.indexOf(secondDoc.doc_status);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to add one more criteria to the sorting function:

```
items.sort(function(firstDoc, secondDoc) {
    if(firstDoc.doc_requirement == 0 && secondDoc.doc_requirement != 0) return 1;
    else if(firstDoc.doc_requirement != 0 && secondDoc.doc_requirement == 0) return -1;
    // Then sort by doc_status
    var order = [2,0,1,3];
    return (order.indexOf(firstDoc.doc_status) - order.indexOf(secondDoc.doc_status));
});
```

Comment: Does not place doc_requirment = 0 elements at last @Tuyen

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this-

```
items.sort(function(doc1,doc2){
  if(doc1.doc_requirement=== 0){
    return 1;
  }
  if(doc2.doc_requirement=== 0){
    return -1;
  }
   return doc1.doc_status > doc2.doc_status;
  })
```

Comment: Does not place doc_requirment = 0 elements at last @krrish

Comment: @AryanKanwar Should place it in last now instead of first.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
var finalSortedDocuments = items.sort(function(firstDoc,secondDoc){
    if(firstDoc.doc_status== 0){
         return(1);
    }
    if(secondDoc.doc_status== 0){
         return(-1);
    }
    return firstDoc.doc_status-secondDoc.doc_status;
});
```